# auto adjustable textview changing height android

Tags: android, textview, height, autosize

i have one `Textview` which text size is auto i am assigning text on API response but its height is changing.

how can i pervert to change its height i set min and max line fix to set fix height but it's not working in some case

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFeedTitle"
        style="@style/komuTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="@dimen/feed_header_font_max_size"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="@dimen/feed_header_font_size"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:text="Covid News Live Updates: After Pfizer, Serum Institute seeks indemnity over COVID-19 vaccine, says sources"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/feed_header_font_size"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgFeed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline" />
```

this is my `Textview`

**1**
[image]

**2**
[image]

I am showing everything in `Recyclerview`

Please help me, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems fine, the text size is auto adjusting according to the text length. Is this not what you want? If not you can set a fixed text size.

Comment: textview is adjusting size correctly but see second image it's showing extra space when text is 3 line

Comment: That could be due to `android:minLines="3"`, I don't know how minLines work with auto text size, but try removing it and seeing if that works.

Comment: @che10 the height should stay same

Comment: The height of the whole text View you mean should be fixed and inside it the text size should auto-adjust? If that is what you mean then since `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` that is what it is causing this.

Comment: yes if i remove minline then size of textview stay same in all item

Comment: Height and size are two different things. Height is changing for now since your `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is set to wrap_content. As for textSize that gets auto adjusted.

Comment: to avoid this problem that's why i set min line 3

Comment: `android:minLines="3"` makes sure your textView will occupy at least 3 lines of space regardless of how many it is currently taking.

Comment: for now, i am setting the static height of textview and removing min line but i don't sure this is the proper solution

Comment: please post as anwer

Comment: If you want, you can set a bottom constraint and set height to 0dp